# Concordion execute Fixture different project

Tags: maven, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, concordion

I have one root maven project with multiple modules, and every one of each has its own integration tests.

I've created another module under root which has to have a summary of all the tests in the different modules.

I know there is concordion run command, but I don't know how to refer to the concordion specification html files of the other projects.

```
<a concordion:run="concordion" href="pathToOtherProject/Calculator.html">Calculator Service Specifications</a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a dependancy on the test-jar for the other projects (and get the other projects to produce a test-jar). That would make the other Concordion resources accessible.